# deal with many div at the same time

Tags: javascript, php

Say you have several div with different value integers like

```
<div class=d alt=2>3</div>
<div class=d alt=9>5</div>
<div class=d alt=2>3</div>
<div class=d alt=7>9</div>
<div class=d alt=2>2</div>
<div class=d alt=2>7</div>
<div class=d alt=3>3</div>
<div class=d alt=2>5</div>
<div class=d alt=5>4</div>
```

Is it possible to increase the number of each div by the value of its alt using javascript without writing a code for each individual div but rather deal with all div simultaneously.

Comment: You can loop over the elements by class. But why are you using `alt` tag on a `div`. `alt` tags are supposed to be for images as html standard.

Comment: "Increase the number of each div by its alt" - you mean the first `<div>` should have `5` as its text (3 + 2)?

Comment: I'd very much like to hear your explanation for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5535214).

Answer (score 2):

The simplest approach, in modern browsers, that I can think of:

```
var textProperty = 'textContent' in document.body ? 'textContent' : 'innerText';

[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('div.d'), function (a) {
    a[textProperty] = parseFloat(a[textProperty]) + parseFloat(a.getAttribute('data-num'))
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/DyTdR/).

To ensure that we're selecting only those `.d` elements that *have* a `data-num` (to avoid [NaN-related problems](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/DyTdR/2/)) attribute:

```
var textProperty = 'textContent' in document.body ? 'textContent' : 'innerText';

[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('div.d[data-num]'), function (a) {
    a[textProperty] = parseFloat(a[textProperty]) + parseFloat(a.getAttribute('data-num'))
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/DyTdR/1/).

Incidentally, the `alt` attribute is valid ***only*** for `<img />` elements, and *not* for `div` elements. If you must use custom attributes, then use the -*valid*- `data-*` prefixed custom attributes (which will validate under HTML 5, though HTML 4.1 will accept them without trouble); this is why we're using `data-num` in my code rather than `alt`.

Comment: This is nice but he's not using any data-attribute.

Comment: That's true, but s/he should be (as you yourself note).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

It works without "" around class + alt attribute but it's bad practice...
You should also consider to use a data-attribute on the div instead of alt.

```
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('d');
for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    var div = divs[i];
    var altValue = div.getAttribute("alt");
    var divValue = parseInt(div.innerHTML);
    div.innerHTML = divValue + parseInt(altValue);
}
```

**The divs would now look like this:**

```
<div class=d alt=2>5</div>
<div class=d alt=9>14</div>
<div class=d alt=2>5</div>
<div class=d alt=7>16</div>
<div class=d alt=2>4</div>
<div class=d alt=2>9</div>
<div class=d alt=3>6</div>
<div class=d alt=2>7</div>
<div class=d alt=5>9</div>
```

JSFIDDLE WITH QUOTES(Correct HTML): http://jsfiddle.net/3ByfH/1/

JSFIDDLE WITHOUT: http://jsfiddle.net/3ByfH/2/

Comment: Agreed. Use `data-` attributes rather than `alt` tag. http://jsfiddle.net/3ByfH/3/

Comment: thanks JOSEFtw, this code works well however I have problem when I want to use ajax to send the alt value of each div to another php file and the pring the return value on the individual div, so I have some thing like this

    var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('d');
    for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
        var div = divs[i];

 $.ajax({
 type: 'POST',
 url: 'log.php',
 data: 'alt='+$(div).attr("alt"),
 success: function(response){
        div.innerHTML = response;
 }
 }); 
        
    }

however it seems that only the last div changes and takes all the return value.

Comment: Hmm, I think it would be better to do just one Ajaxcall... Get all the divs, send it to your log.php, get back an array of new values from your log.php(I guess?) and in your success method you should loop through them and update your divs. Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/joseftw/AMGmY/6/